Disable Web Part Property pane .... is it possible?
i wanted to know if by making any property false is it possible to hide the property pane flyout feature. I dont want the property pane flyout to open when the edit option is clicked in the webpart. Is it possible.
havent tried anything yet but looking for the solution
thank you!

I'm not aware of a way to do this without getting hacky, but can I ask what your end goal is?
What do you want to happen when you click edit?
Edit opens the property pane on all web parts, it's standard behaviour.
I don't think changing it is a good user experience, the user will likely think something is broken if behvaiour isn't consistent.  I would!
